# Combine or Merge two Collection Flow in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

> Sum the size of two different collection flow.

**ViewModel.kt**

```
    private val _orderPickups: MutableLiveData<List<OrderPickup>> = MutableLiveData()
    val orderPickups: LiveData<List<OrderPickup>> = _orderPickups
    private val orderPickupsFlow = OrderPickupsRepository.instance.getOrderPickups()

    private val _bonusGiftsFlow: MutableLiveData<List<BonusGift>> = MutableLiveData()
    val bonusGifts: LiveData<List<BonusGift>> = _bonusGiftsFlow
    private val bonusGiftsFlow = BrandsRepository.instance.getBonusGifts()
```

I tried **combine** **merge** **zip** but not able to simple get the sum of both of it.

```
viewModelScope.launch { 
            orderPickupsFlow.combine(bonusGiftsFlow){
                
            }
            combine(orderPickupsFlow,bonusGiftsFlow){
                
            }
            merge(orderPickupsFlow,bonusGiftsFlow).collectLatest { 
                
            }
        }
```

I have tried multiple ways but not working

I simply want an Integer count after sum of both `orderPickupFlow` and `bonusGifsFlow`

Answer (score 1):

`combine` would do that for you, I created and tested the following snippet, hope that helps you.

```
    val _orderPickups: MutableSharedFlow<List<Unit>> = MutableSharedFlow()
    val orderPickups: SharedFlow<List<Unit>> = _orderPickups

    val _stringsFlow: MutableSharedFlow<List<String>> = MutableSharedFlow()
    val strings: SharedFlow<List<String>> = _stringsFlow


    runBlocking {
        launch {
//the below is how it can be done
            strings.combine(orderPickups) { string: List<String>, orders: List<Unit> ->
                println("count = ${string.size} , ${orders.size}")
                string.size + orders.size
            }
                .collect { count ->
                    println("count = $count")
                }
        }

//test triggers below
        delay(2000)
        //it takes sometime to start the collector ,
        // if collector is not ready then it would lose all emits
        launch {
            while (bCount < 10) {
                delay(1000)
                _stringsFlow.emit(
                    Array(bCount) { "$bCount" }.toList()
                )
                bCount++
            }
        }

        launch {
            while (aCount < 5) {
                _orderPickups.emit(
                    Array(aCount) { }.toList()
                )
                aCount++
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know that when we use **merge** the elements from one flow do not wait for another flow. For instance, in the example below, elements from the first flow are delayed, but this does not stop the elements from the second flow.

The next function is **zip**, which makes pairs from both flows. We also need to specify a function that decides how elements are paired (transformed into one what will be emitted in the new flow). Each element can only be part of one pair, so it needs to wait for its pair. Elements left without a pair are lost, so when the zipping of a flow is complete, the resulting flow is also complete (as is the other flow).

The last important function when combining two flows is **combine**. Just like zip, it also forms pairs from elements, which have to wait for the slower flow to produce the first pair. However, the similarities to the polonaise dance end here. When we use combine, every new element replaces its predecessor. If the first pair has been formed already, it will produce a new pair together with the previous element from the other flow.

Result - merge would be a better option in your case. In this case you will get first amount and then it might be changed to sum after another value is retrieved.

Link to resource - https://kt.academy/article/cc-flow-combine